# Убрать пустое пространство после шапки (навигации). Тема Twenty Seventeen

Tags: css, wordpress

После навигации (меню) большой отступ, как его убрать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Постарайтесь изложить всю суть проблемы в самом вопросе без лишних ссылок на сторонние сайты. Приведите, пожалуйста, ваш код и, если вы хотите показать что-то более наглядно, скриншот, демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Выделите проблемное место кода и добавьте в вопрос иначе его проигнорируют. Читайте тут, как что оформлять:https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: я не знаю какая часть кода отвечает за отступ, если бы знал, не задавал бы вопрос тут.

Comment: @Oleksii Вы поймите, это как иголку в стоге сена искать.

Comment: поэтому я вставил ссылку на сайт, где можно посмотреть код. Вставил скриншот, может понятнее будет.... стандартный шаблон вордпресса....

Comment: @Oleksii ссылки на сторонние ресурсы большинство игнорирует, я вам из-за этого дал ссылку как оформлять вопрос.

Comment: Можно было бы и скриншот из dev tools браузера, с html разметкой.

Comment: @Oleksii Попробуйте данный вам ответ. Если подошел и решение работает, тогда примите его. Все-таки правила. Да и общее взаимоуважение.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, буду пользоваться теперь вашим сайтом, первый раз просто и так быстро дали ответ, который помог!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в style.css вашей темы

```
.panel-content .wrap {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Но лучше создать [дочернюю тему](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html) и добавить этот код в ее style.css.

Comment: Спасибо огромное вы меня спасли!

Comment: Да уж прям спас )))

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: А подскажешь как увеличить пространство между ссылками в меню? А то много места пустого

Comment: Например, так .main-navigation a {
    padding: 1em 1em;
}

Comment: Но вообще-то, осваивайте css.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!! с чего посоветуешь начать освоение?

Comment: А вот с таких практических вопросов. Разберитесь, что такое dev tools в браузере, поймите, откуда что у элемента, спросите гугл, как изменить padding

Comment: Ещё один вариант — добавить код в Внешний вид -> Настроить -> Дополнительные стили.